# How to make a simple script in MYSQL Workbench to execute a query and export results into a CSV

Tags: python, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I'm really new at coding.

I'm just trying to figure out how to make a simple script for Mysql Workbench that it just runs a given query, and then exports the results into a CSV.

I know this works for executing the query:

```
import grt

result = grt.root.wb.sqlEditors[0].executeScript("givenquery")
```

But I'm stuck at what to do next to export the results into a csv.

Thanks in advance.

ps: Yes, this has to be a script to run inside mysql workbench scripting shell enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.5

```
import csv
import grt


result = grt.root.wb.sqlEditors[0].executeScript("givenquery")


with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for res in result:
        spamwriter.writerow(result)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the help!
I'm getting this error:    

Uncaught exception while executing /home/ltreduca/.mysql/workbench/scripts/test.py:
  File "/home/ltreduca/.mysql/workbench/scripts/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: seems you are using python 2.7. What verson of python is used?